# PdhEnumObjectsW issue

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi

I have an issue with enumerating performance counter objects. My code worked well for a few years, but recently I have found it started to fail to get counter objects with the following error:

> **PDH_CSTATUS_NO_MACHINE** The path did not contain a computer name, and the function was unable to retrieve the local computer name.

```cpp
DWORD bufLength = 0;
const DWORD detailLevel = PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD;
PDH_STATUS objStatus = PdhEnumObjectsW(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, &bufLength, detailLevel, TRUE);
qDebug() << ManageApp::getPdhStatusMsg(objStatus);
qDebug() << "bufLength: " << bufLength;
std::wstring namebuf(bufLength, '\0');
PDH_STATUS status = PdhEnumObjectsW(nullptr, nullptr, &namebuf[0], &bufLength, detailLevel, FALSE);
qDebug() << ManageApp::getPdhStatusMsg(status);
```

I have tried to get the computer name and set it in the `PdhEnumObjectsW()` call:

```cpp
PDH_STATUS objStatus = PdhEnumObjectsW(nullptr, machineName.toStdWString().c_str(), nullptr, &bufLength, detailLevel, TRUE);
```

```cpp
WCHAR computerName[MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1];
DWORD computerNameSize = _countof(computerName);
bool isComputerName = GetComputerNameExW(ComputerNameDnsFullyQualified, computerName, &computerNameSize);
qDebug() << isComputerName;
QString machineName = "";
```

I have removed the Windows 10 update and switched back to 19044.1645, but it still displays the `PDH_CSTATUS_NO_MACHINE` error. Also, I have checked it in a VM - Windows 10 build 19043, Windows 11 and Windows 11 Insider Preview, so it works well there.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/pdh/nf-pdh-pdhconnectmachinea), I get following error description:

> **PDH_CSTATUS_NO_MACHINE**
>
> Unable to connect to the specified computer. Could be caused by the computer not being on, not supporting PDH, not being connected to the network, or having the permissions set on the registry that prevent remote connections or remote performance monitoring by the user.

So, I think it's somehow related to registry permissions. Any ideas how to verify that all registry permissions for PDH are properly set on my machine?

I have checked out the registry permissions for `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib`, and all permissions are set properly. So, I do not think, it is related to the registry permissions.

Any ideas what could cause such `PDH_CSTATUS_NO_MACHINE` issue?

Comment: `DWORD computerNameSize = sizeof(computerName);` is wrong for `GetComputerNameW()`, it wants the array length in *characters* not *bytes*. Also, since you are using a `W` API directly, you should be using `WCHAR` instead of `TCHAR`. You are also not checking the return value of `GetComputerNameW()` for success before using `computerName`.

Comment: Well, now you have made the code worse, as `computerNameSize` is now *uninitialized*. You need to set it to the max number of characters the array can hold, eg: `DWORD computerNameSize = MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH + 1;` or `DWORD computerNameSize = _countof(computerName);`

Comment: In any case, this is secondary to your main issue, since you have the same problem when passing `nullptr` for the computer name. Something on your machine is preventing PDH from functioning correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
Yes, you are right. This issue still exists.
It occurs on 2 PCs and laptop. Thanks.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
It is not only on my machine. Any ideas what could prevent the `PDH` from functioning correctly? Thank you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
I think, something not preventing but broke the performance counters on 2 PCs and laptop. I have already fixed it. I will submit the answer with the fix instructions soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it by rebuilding the performance counters.

**Instructions:**

1. Set "Disable Performance Counters" to 0 using this command:

   `Reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance /v "Disable Performance Counters" /t REG_DWORD /d 0`
2. Rebuild all performance counters:

   `%windir%\system32\lodctr /R`

   `%windir%\sysWOW64\lodctr /R`

When running the first command - `%windir%\system32\lodctr /R`, you will get:

> Error: Unable to rebuild performance counter setting from system
> backup store, error code is 2

In such case, feel free run this command first - `%windir%\sysWOW64\lodctr /R` and then run `%windir%\system32\lodctr /R`. The second time after this command: `%windir%\sysWOW64\lodctr /R` it will complete successfully for `%windir%\system32\lodctr /R`:

> Info: Successfully rebuilt performance counter setting from system
> backup store

3. Resync the counters with Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI): `%windir%\system32\wbem\winmgmt.exe /resyncperf`
4. Stop and restart the Performance Logs and Alerts service with the following commands:

   `net stop pla`

   `net start pla`
5. Stop and restart the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) service by using these commands:

   `net stop winmgmt`

   `net start winmgmt`

So, the issue is resolved. Thanks.